# Mapping CSV data to customized fileds

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Java Spring boot and I am trying to read data from a CSV file and then pass this data to my UI via REST.

I am using `OpenCSV` to parse my file. Here is my sample line in my file
firstname, lastname, card details.

card details consists of **card number** and **expiry date**. So my example text looks like:

```
joe, keller, 123456 22-2-1999.
```

The output from my rest end point should be:

```
{
  "firstname": "joe",
  "lastname" : "keller",
  "card number" : "123456",
  "expiry date" : 22-2-1999
}
```

I currently read the file using `CsvToBeanBuilder` and I seem to get stuck with mapping the final line to two different items.

Comment: I think there should be a ',' between the last two numbers.

Comment: You need to add more details so we can understand where the mapping is going wrong. Can you provide a snippet of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the last column contains 2 fields - **card number** and **expiry date**, you cannot directly use `CsvToBeanBuilder` to read CSV file and convert it to your POJO. A alternative way is shown as follows:

First, I assume that you have already a POJO looks like:

```
class CreditCardInfo {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String cardNumber;
    private String expiryDate;

    //general getters and setters
    //toString()
}
```

Then you can use `CSVReader.readNext()` to read each line into a string array. And for the 3-rd column in CSV file you can separate it into 2 fields by empty space(" "): "123456" and "22-2-1999" with `String.trim()` for ignoring leading space. Therefore, you can store these fields to `cardNumber` and `expiryDate` of the POJO `CreditCardInfo`, respectively.

**Code snippet**

```
try (
    Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("So58792579.csv"));
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
) {
    String[] nextRecord;
    while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
        CreditCardInfo creditCardInfo = new CreditCardInfo();
        creditCardInfo.setFirstname(nextRecord[0]);
        creditCardInfo.setLastname(nextRecord[1].trim()); //trim() for ignoring leading space
        creditCardInfo.setCardNumber(nextRecord[2].trim().split(" ")[0]);
        creditCardInfo.setExpiryDate(nextRecord[2].trim().split(" ")[1]);

        System.out.println(creditCardInfo.toString());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Console output**

> CreditCardInfo [firstname=joe, lastname=keller, cardNumber=123456, expiryDate=22-2-1999]